# How to make a POST call using RestTemplate with a Json body and header?

Tags: java, spring, rest, post, resttemplate

How to make a POST call using RestTemplate with a Json body and header? The Json body I want to post has a complex structure.

```
{
    "foo": "long",
    "bar": {
        "foo": {
            "foo": [
                "long"
            ]
        },
        "fiz": [
            null
        ],
        "sides": [
            null
        ],
        "biz": ""
    },
    "biz": {
        "boo": "",
        "li": [
            null
        ],
        "biz": {
            "bzo": "",
            "lsp": ""
        },
        "baz": "",
        "bar": ""
    }
}
```

Request Body

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve. And the tags you selected seem unrelated as well.

Comment: Hey @Raptor , I want to invoke a rest endpoint. Post call with above mentioned Response body

Comment: And what have you tried already?

Answer (score 1):

`RestTemplate` provides `exchange()` method to call other HTTP urls with uri, HTTP methods, HTTP entity and response-class as method parameters.

Signature of RestTemplate's exchange method is:

> restTemplate.exchange(url, method, requestEntity, responseType);

For e.g. :

```
//wrapping stringified request-body and HTTP request-headers into HTTP entity and passing it in exchange() method...    
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, requestHeaders); 

restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/context-path/resource", HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
```

In case you have any path-variables in your url, then RestTemplate also provides overridden method which accepts Map for path-variables:

> restTemplate.exchange(url, method, requestEntity, responseType,
>   pathVariables);

Comment: Hey @Harsh Thanks...What if my requestBody is a custom object? 
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(Object, requestHeaders); 
throws the error : "constructor HttpEntity<String>(Object, HttpHeaders) is undefined"

Comment: @TheLastJedi, let's say if your requestBody is a custom object (e.g. an object of Class A), then you need to initiate HttpEntity<> for your custom class:

e.g.:
A a = new A();
HttpEntity<A> entity = new HttpEntity<>(a,requestHeaders);